# Do I need to put more focus on making armour and weapons?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How important is it to get my military squads fully equipped? I'm having a really rough time surviving any goblin ambushes.

Comment: Antony, what question do you want answered, "Why are the goblins ambushing" or "how important is it to have fully equipped squads"?

Comment: @C. Ross The latter. I was trying too hard to make the title catchy.

Comment: Don't shoot for catchy titles. Use a title that describes or summarizes what you're actually asking about. Otherwise, people get confused over what is being asked and it won't be easy to get an answer.

Comment: How many militia are you running antony and how are they equipped?

Comment: @C. Ross I'm going with the formula round_up(pop/10). So far I've had within one same number of militia as ambushers, but armor has been ad-hoc(cloth mostly, if that even counts).

Comment: @Grace got it. I edited the title before I conceded my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're having trouble with ambushers, there are multiple defenses you can employ to defend your fortress.

- Troops

  - This is the most flexible, but also most time intensive way to defend your area.
  - Requires dwarves, weapons, and armor.
- Walls

  - A fixed defense, but can completely stop current goblin ambushers.
  - Requires stone (usually abundant) and masons.
- Traps

  - A fixed defense, but it can stop most ambushes.
  - Requires stone, mechanics, and sometimes weapons.
- A moat (or other terrain features)

  - A fixed defense, but the simplest of defenses.
  - Just miners
- War animals

  - A fairly strong defense.  Usually dogs, but more effective with bears, etc.
  - Tame animals, and an animal trainer.

Most people combine these in some arrangement.  You will need *some* sort of defense in dwarf fortress because you're almost guaranteed to be attached by something.

Comment: I'd like to add minecarts to this. Minecarts are versatile and devastating in their applications. Have the invaders enter through the muzzle of a minecart railgun. Have them navigate a minecart blender. Launch sharp or heavy objects, water, magma or even rotten body parts from a previous siege through fortifications at the advancing enemy. Have your crossbowmen do drive-by shootings!